# How to choose a decoding algorithm with AWGN performance

Tags: digital-communications

Decoding algorithms for convolutional code, turbo code, ldpc code and so on, are usually evaluated in AWGN channel. They are finally used with other receiver modules in fading channels. The performance difference in AWGN channel between decoding algorithms may be small like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.5dB. The question is should I choose an algorithm for the 0.2 or 0.5dB gain? Why does this 0.2 or 0.5dB gain matter? If not then how much gain matters?

Comment: Usually you have some design constraints and/or objectives regarding performance, complexity, energy consumption, latency, etcetera; then, choose the simplest algorithm that meets your constraints/objectives.

Comment: I actually want to ask if and why 0.2 or 0.5dB in AWGN channel matters when applied in practice in fading channel.

Comment: @c1119 if you can have 0.2 or 0.5dB gain, why not? It would be easier if you tell us why you don't want such gain(s).

Comment: @AlexTP I didn't mean I don't want the gain. I just wonder the gain looks so small in AWGN and may be amplified in fading channel and want to understand the theory behind it. I have a feeling that it may be related to the distribution of SNR.